# Grammar of "will" plus "have to" plus "have+pp"

Tags: grammar, will-future

Is this sentence correct?

> **I will have to have done this** (in two years for example).

What I want to say is : there is a task to be done in 2 years from now. this sentence is referring to the end of the 2 years in future.

Please tell me which one is correct:

- I will have to have done this in 2 years from now.
- I will have to have done this by the end of the year(one year for example).

I mean, should it refer to the "End" or to the "Duration"?

Comment: Why this structure? *I must have this done by [date]* is easier to understand.

Comment: @Davo right, but what if i wanna say s.th should have been done at then?

Comment: I thought OP was asking about future past perfect:  In order for me to get across the bridge tomorrow you will have had to disable the alarm system before I get there or we’ll both be toast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I will have to have this done by [date].** - Correct; date may be absolute (20 June 2019) or relative (two years from today).

**I will have to have this done in [duration].** - Also correct.

Please note: *two years* may be understood as a generalization; it is best to specify a date when the date is important.

Comment: If you're specifying a date, the one ending 'by' is correct, not 'in'.